# Manipulating multi dimensional hash?

Tags: perl, hash

---

I have a script that takes in various data and gives me the mean of each functional relationship in the data.

```perl
while ( <IN> ) {
    chomp $_;

    if ($_ =~ m/Source/ ) {
        next;
    }
    else{

        @arr = split(/\t/, $_);

        $freq  = $arr[2];
        $term1 = $arr[4];
        $term2 = $arr[11];

        push ( @{ $hash{$term1}{$term2} }, $freq);
    }
}

## Gathers sum of all arrays for each function
foreach my $val ( keys %hash ) {

    foreach my $val2 ( keys %{ $hash{$val} } ) {

        my $count = sum (@{ $hash{$val}{$val2} });
        $total += $count;
    }
}

## calculates mean for each function
foreach my $val ( keys %hash ) {

    foreach my $val2 ( keys %{ $hash{$val} } ) {

        my $count = sum (@{ $hash{$val}{$val2} });
        my $avg   = $count/$total;

        print "$val\t$val2\t$avg\n";
    }
 }
```

#### Example output

```
GIY-YIG catalytic domain        Unknown 0.24
Endonucelase VII        TEST    0.16
TEST    Endonucelase VII        0.16
Unknown GIY-YIG catalytic domain        0.12
Unknown Unknown 0.32
```

But I need to combine any inverse function that isn't `Unknown`.

#### Desired output

```
GIY-YIG catalytic domain        Unknown 0.24  <-stays the same
Endonucelase VII        TEST    0.32          <-changes
Unknown GIY-YIG catalytic domain        0.12  <--stays the same
Unknown Unknown 0.32
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my %data;
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   my ($term1, $term2, $freq) = split /\t/;
   if ($term1 eq "Unknown" || $term2 eq "Unknown") {
      say;
      next;
   }

   ($term1, $term2) = sort ($term1, $term2);
   $data{"$term1\t$term2"} += $freq;
}

say "$_\t$data{$_}" for keys %data;
```

Comment: `$; = "\t";  ... $data{$term1, $term2} += $freq;` (but don't do that)

Comment: Really really really don't do that. Why did you mention that?!

Comment: @ysth Teaching something really dangerous, then teaching to not use it :D